# assigning value to 2d array is giving me exception

Tags: c#, arrays

I am trying to assign values to 0th position of a 2D integer array. However, I get a NullReferenceException exception, though I am passing proper values.

```
public static int[,] Ctable;

private static void GetTable(int m,int n)
{
    m = 16;
    for (int i = 1; i <= m; i++)
    {
        Ctable[i, 0] = 1; // Here it is giving Exception
    }
}
```

Comment: Your Ctable is null, this is your problem, check the question which I post. Learn what is debug

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't initialize the 2D array `Ctable` correctly, it's still null. See my example below. I initialize the array with the size of the input parameter `m` and `n` of the method `void GetTable(int m, int n)`.

Your loop is not correct as well. Arrays are zero indexed (0, n - 1). You will find some additional information to initialize arrays [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287601(v=vs.71).aspx).

```
public static int[,] Ctable;

private static void GetTable(int m, int n)
{
    Ctable = new int[m, n]; // Initialize array here.

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) // Iterate i < m not i <= m.
    {
        Ctable[i, 0] = 1;
    }
}
```

However, you will always overwrite `Ctable`. Probably you're looking for something like:

```
private const int M = 16; // Size of the array element at 0.

private const int N = 3; // Size of the array element at 1.

public static int[,] Ctable = new int [M, N]; // Initialize array with the size of 16 x 3.

private static void GetTable()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
        Ctable[i, 0] = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can show the usage and data filling for index n too, here it only fills index m. Mostly OP doesn't know that well.